# Tipos de datos: CHAR e INTEGER

Tags: base-de-datos, tipos

Buenas tardes ¿Cuál sería la diferencia entre un tipo de dato CHAR y un INTEGER?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Por favor, leé [ask]. Si querés hacer una pregunta del tipo _cuál es la diferencia entre x e y_ debés describir en la pregunta lo que entendiste (o no) hasta el momento, y lo que ya has investigado anteriormente. No está demás recordar que [es.so] _no es un foro_. Además, no coloques meta-etiquetas (etiquetas ambiguas): ¿estás haciendo referencia a SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso que mencionas son tipos de datos enteros, existen algunos más y cada uno está pensando con algún propósito en específico. Supongo que lo que buscas es la diferencia entre Char e Int, ya que Integer es algo distinto, que en Java es conocido como un objeto o clase.

**Char:** El tipo entero char ocupa en espacio de memoria 1 byte (8 bits) y permite representar en el sistema numérico binario 2^8 valores = 256. Este tipo de dato puede contener los valores positivos, igual que negativos; y su rango de valores está definido de -128 a 127

**Integer:** El tipo entero int ocupa en espacio de memoria 4 bytes (32 bits). Su valor mínimo es de -2 147 483 648, y el valor máximo que puede llegar a tomar es de 2 147 483 647.

Te invito a consultar mas sobre los tipos de datos que existen, en ellos encontrarás los enteros, los lógicos, las cadenas de caracteres, entre otros más.

Comment: ¡Gracias! Entonces INTEGER no es un tipo de dato?

Comment: Hice un comentario, y lo borré porque noté que el OP puso en las etiquetas "base de datos". La respuesta aquí está basada en Java.